# Two images display in different sizes under same code

Tags: html, css, image, size

I have a problem with a png logo image that for some reason is displayed in different sizes on two otherwise identical webpages. The only difference is that the pages are in different language.

The first example where everything is as it should is at [contact](http://www.kimwist.com/contact.html)

The second page, in different language with excatly the same css and settings is at [contact in Finnish](http://www.kimwist.com/taikureita.html)

The logo on the second page is wrong size and I have not been able to figure out why this happens.

The only change I made, was to change the relative padding in the taikurit.html page, to get the text inside the logo more centered. But still the logo image is wrong size and everything is otherwise the same with these two pages.

Note that all my css to control the pages is currently inlined, this is because I do testing with page-speed.

On line 158 is the only difference, which I mentioned above:

```
.logo2 h1{position:relative;padding:20px 0 79px;font-size:120px;line-height:120px;display:inline-block;color:#fff}
```

If someone knows why this happens, I would be very happy because I have looked at the code for two days now without understanding the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lays in the next piece of code:

```
<span itemprop="name">Magician</span>
```

In the second example the logo is wrong sized (smaller) because "TAIKURI" is smaller than "MAGICIAN". Try putting in the first example a shorter text (or larger), you will see how the logo changes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, the logo gets bigger with more letters, but not the spacing. Look at this page: www.kimwist.com/taikurit.html there is the same logo and same word without any problems. So there must be another solution

Comment: Hi again Fernando! I made some tests and realized that you were uttering words of wisdom :) I added some &nbsp; s to the word and changed some padding settings and now everything works fine. Can be tricky designing web pages in three different languages sometimes.

Comment: Hi Kim. Also pay attention to this: You are enclosing between `<h1>` tags some content, and that is the beginning of your problem. Note that you are specifying your logo to be 526x244, but is rendered smaller (in all of the 3 pages), that is because of the `<h1>` tag enclosing. If you replace that for `<div>`, then the logo will be rendered at the specified size. That, in the other hand, will make some things render incorrectly and will be necessary adjust the css. If you need some more help fixing things, just ask for.
Greetings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Fernando! I could very well replace the h1 with div, but then I don't know how to handle the most important keyword "taikuri" which should be inside h1 tags. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, try to associate the next css style to the brand new `<div>` tag (you should use a class when debugging is done):
`position: relative; display: inline-block; left: 13%;`. Then, associate the next css to the existing `<span>` tag (again, use a class when debugging is done): `position: relative; color: #fff; font-size: 120px;line-height: 120px; right: 50%; top: 55px;`. Note that the logo now is rendered bigger than before. That is because now is rendered at the size specified. If you want it smaller, change width and height (better if specified in css, no html as now).

Comment: I have a question for you Fernando, but unrelated to this topic. Is here a way to use a chat or private messaging?